# Can't draw to JPanel with getGraphics

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, graphics, jpanel

I was wondering what went wrong. I've done this before but for some reason I can't get this to work this time.

I designed the project in Netbeans. The most relevant part is the method initTiras, which is suppossed to draw something, but it doesn't. I included the code generated by NetBeans.

Here's the most simplified version of the code, and still it paints nothing.

So I created a new Frame in the proyect. Then I put a JPanel in it (in desing mode). The JPanel's called ElPanel and the JFrame LaFrame.

Here's the main class:

```
package ElPackage;
public class Resistores {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LaFrame UnaFrame = new LaFrame();
        UnaFrame.setVisible(true);
    }   
}
```

Inside the LaFrame class:

```
package ElPackage;

import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public class LaFrame extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    public LaFrame () {
        initComponents();
        initTiras();
    }

    public void initTiras() {
        Graphics LasG = ElPanel.getGraphics();
        LasG.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        LasG.fillRect(10, 10, 30, 30);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        ElPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(false);

        ElPanel.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 0, 51));
        ElPanel.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout ElPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(ElPanel);
        ElPanel.setLayout(ElPanelLayout);
        ElPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
            ElPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        ElPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
            ElPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(ElPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(ElPanel, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        
    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JPanel ElPanel;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Override `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method of elPanel and add your code there. See [for example](http://www.java2s.com/Code/JavaAPI/javax.swing/JPanelpaintComponentGraphicsg.htm)

Use java naming convention - variables should start from lowercase letter.

Comment: Read the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html). I find the tutorial does a better job at explaining how custom painting works that does a simple example found of the web.

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you, I finished reading the tutorial. But shouldn't it have worked the way I used it? I mean, it worked once, I don't exactly know why but it did in another project where I managed the Graphics of a JPanel in the code of a JFrame.